# Changing the color in multiple class li item

Tags: css, hover, html-lists

I am using the pagesrcoller demo and trying to make some changes.

```
    <div class="pageScrollerNav topNav light">
    <ul>
        <li><img style="padding: 25px 145px 30px 0px" src="./images/logo_demo.png" height="25" /></li>
        <li><a href="#">index</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
        <li class="bloger"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

i use the class bloger for the last li item to change its color
here is the css

```
    .topNav li a{
    display: block;
    height: 18px;
    margin: 25px 0 0;
    line-height: 16px;
    padding: 7px 15px;
    color: #666;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.topNav li.bloger a{
    display: block;
    height: 18px;
    margin: 25px 0 0;
    line-height: 16px;
    padding: 7px 15px;
    color: #049bd9;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.topNav,
.topNav.light{
    background: #fff;
}

.topNav li.active a,
.topNav.light li.active a{
    background: #f0f0f0;
    color: #444444;
    border-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.topNav li a,
.topNav.light li a{
    color: #444444;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.topNav li.active .bloger a{
    background: #9be2ff;
    color: #049bd9;
    border-color: #9be2ff;
}

.topNav li.bloger a{
    color: #049bd9;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

the color is changed when i am on other li items but not on it
is this the fault?

```
    .topNav li.active .bloger a{
    background: #9be2ff;
    color: #049bd9;
    border-color: #9be2ff;
}
```

how can i change multiple class items?

Comment: I've just tried out your code, and there are no colour changes on hover. It is possible that your other stylesheets are conflicting or blending with the stylesheet that you've included on your question.

Comment: What element are you hovering over, and what elements are you trying to change?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space between **.active** & .**bloger** class.Write like this:

```
.topNav li.active.bloger a{....}
```

Instead of this:

```
.topNav li.active .bloger a{....}
```

Answer (score 0):

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/diAuhERC)***

Hi now

**replace**

```
.topNav li.active .bloger a
```

**into this**

```
   .topNav .bloger a
```

***[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/diAuhERC)***

### -----------------------------------------

### --------------------------------------------

Second is used to this hover as like this

```
  .topNav li:hover a,  .bloger a{
    background: #9be2ff;
    color: #049bd9;
    border-color: #9be2ff;
}
```

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/XmkJH5cb)***

Answer (score 0):

Editing multiple classes is simple.

All you have to do is delineate them with a comma!

Example:

HTML:

```
<div class='box1'></div>
<div class='box2'></div>
```

CSS:

```
.box1,.box2{
    color:red;
}
```